# Schedule Delivery Time and Date

Tags: commerce

Is there a module from Drupal Commerce to schedule Delivery date and time ?

Customer is required to specify the date and time. This then will be displayed in the admin side.

thanks appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Check it out [Commerce Field Group Panes](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_fieldgroup_panes) module. Using this you can able to add field Delivery Date & Time field to check out process.

> This enables an easy way to collect information in the checkout
>   process. For example customer comments, feedback about where the
>   customer founds the shop or any other fieldable information.

Comment: This combined with [Date](http://www.drupal.org/project/date) would definitely do the job.